1 - Step Ahead Conditional Distribution
I started reading a paper, McNeil and Frey (2000), where they introduce the following:

Let $(X_t)_{t \in \, \mathbb{Z}}$ be a strictly stationary time series (...). We assume
that the dynamics of $X$ are given by
\begin{equation*}
X_t = \mu_t + \sigma_t \cdot Z_t \quad \forall \, t \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{equation*}
where the innovations $Z_t$ are a strict white noise process (i.e. independent,
identically distributed) with zero mean, unit variance and marginal distribution
function $F_Z(z)$. We assume that $\mu_t$ and $\sigma_t$ are measurable with respect to $\mathcal{G}_{t - 1}$, the information about the return process available up to time $t - 1$.

and later on they derive the 1 - Step Ahead Conditional distribution

\begin{equation*}
F_{X_{t + 1} \, | \, \mathcal{G}_t}(x) = P(\mu_{t + 1} + \sigma_{t + 1} \cdot Z_{t + 1} \, \leq \, x \, | \, \mathcal{G}_t) \, = \, F_Z((x - \mu_{t + 1})/\sigma_{t + 1}).
\end{equation*}

I have a few questions about the last equality in the 1 - Step Ahead Conditiona Distribution:

Why is it true that the conditional distribution of $X_{t + 1} | \mathcal{G}_t$ is equal to the unconditional distribution of $Z$ ($Z_t$ all have the same distribution, so the author uses $F_Z$) composed with the $\mathcal{G}_t$ - measurable function $(x - \mu_{t + 1})/\sigma_{t + 1}$? Can someone prove this to me?

The second question ties in with the first:

Do we require the strict stationarity assumption for this equality to hold?

To give context to the second question, let us forget about the stochastic nature of our problem and consider the following

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ be a sub $\sigma$ - algebra, $X, Z : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be random variables, $\mu, \sigma : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $\mathcal{G}$ - measurable, $\sigma > 0$ a.e. - $P$ and assume that
\begin{equation*}
X = \mu + \sigma \cdot Z.
\end{equation*}
Is it the case that
\begin{equation*}
F_{X \, | \, \mathcal{G}}(\omega, x) = F_Z((x - \mu(\omega))/\sigma(\omega))?
\end{equation*}

Thing is, I think I created a counterexample to this second situation and (it feels like) it should invalidate the first equality, but I'm not 100% sure, so I would like an opinion (or proof).

$\mu$ and $\sigma$ being $\mathcal{G}$-measurable means that when you condition on $\mathcal{G}$, you can view $\mu$ and $\sigma$ as "non-random"/"constant."

@angryavian I don't think that is quite the case, at least not on the second example: Just consider something like $({ 1, 2, 3}, \mathcal{P}({1, 2, 3}), P)$, $P(1) = P(3) = 1/4$ and $P(2) = 1/2$. Also, define $\mathcal{G} = { \emptyset, \Omega, { 2 }, { 1, 3 } }$, $Z = 1 = \sigma$, and $\mu(1) = 0$ and $\mu(2) = \mu(3) = - 1$. For any $x \in (0, 1/2)$, we have $F_Z((x - \mu(\omega))/\sigma(\omega)) = 1_{{2, 3 }}$, while $P(\mu + \sigma \cdot Z \leq x , | , \mathcal{G} )(\omega) = 1_{{2}} + (1/2) \cdot 1_{{1, 3}}$. So they disagree everywhere on $(0, 1/2)$.

Either there is something wrong with my reasoning in the example above or this doesn't translate to the problem found in the paper (or the equality doesn't hold). I'm just struggling to understand which.

In your example, $\mu$ is not $\mathcal{G}$-measurable?

@angryavian You are right, but I tweaked the example. It is easier (and I hope correct this time): Consider the same probability space and sub sigma algebra $\mathcal{G}$ as before. Now, let $\sigma = 1$ and $\mu = 0$ (both $\mathcal{G}$ measurable), but this time let $Z(1) = 1$ and $Z(2) = Z(3) = 0$. Then for any $x \in (0, 1/2)$, $F_Z((x - \mu(\omega)/\sigma(\omega)) = 3/4$, while $P(\mu + \sigma \cdot Z , | , \mathcal{G})(\omega) = 1_{{ 2 }} + (1/2) \cdot 1_{{1, 3}}$. What seems to be the problem is the freedom we give $Z$.

Now the problem is that $Z$ is not independent of $\mathcal{G}$. I think this independence assumption is a condition that needs to be added to your simplified problem. In the original problem I think independence of $Z_t$ and $\mathcal{G}{t-1}$ is implicit: you are already given that $Z_t$ is independent of $Z{t-1}, \ldots, Z_1$, but it should also be independent of the processes $(\mu_t)$ and $(\sigma_t)$.

@angryavian So what you are saying is that the authors are not using an arbitrary filtration $(\mathcal{G}t){t \in \mathbb{Z}}$ but the particular one where $\mathcal{G}t = \sigma({ X_s , | , s \leq t })$ and, in this context, $Z{t + 1}$ is  independent of $\mathcal{G}_{t}$? So in the simplified problem, because of the lack of indepence equality doesn't hold.

I'm just not entirely sure I understood the necessity of independence between $Z_t$ and $\mu_t$ and $\sigma_t$.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
